# Looking for a formula to create a list of 301 redirects (old url to new url) using excel, matching by ID

Tags: excel-formula

**Sheet 1**

Column A = number value

Column B = link

Column C =

**Sheet 2**

Column A = number value

Column B = link

I tried a combo of "IF=COUNTIF" AND "VLOOKUPS" and am running into difficulties.

I need to copy the value of Column B in Sheet 2, to Column C on Sheet 1, if the ID matches in Column A on both sheets.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Q4ZUSrbRnBLqjyEGVGTSv919GBVpPHcDWi7I74sOqjY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Show what you did for 'vlookup'. That should work

Answer (score 0):

I have added the formula to the shared doc but here it is below.

Use this formula: =IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A5,Sheet2!$A$2:$B$7,2,FALSE),"No URL")

Don't forget to change your range in the Vlookup if your table expands.